# Текст при создании вопроса незарегистрированным пользователем

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, новые-участники

Заметил довольно интересную вещь у [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Если к ним на сайт приходит пользователь, который не зарегистрирован в системе, то ему сначала показывается [страница](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice?) со следующим текстом:

> Welcome to Server Fault!
>
> To improve the chances of your question staying open and getting an answer, make sure that it is about **managing information technology systems in a business environment**. If your question concerns personal equipment, [try asking on Super User](https://superuser.com/about) instead. Here are some additional tips:
>
> ### Search, and research
>
> Have you **[thoroughly searched for an answer](/search)** *before* asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps *you* get a more specific and relevant answer!
>
> Try our more [advanced search](/search)!
>
> ### Be on-topic
>
> Our community is defined by a [specific set of topics in the help center](/help/on-topic); please stick to those topics and [avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion](/help/dont-ask). If your question is about the site itself, ask on our [meta-discussion site](http://meta.serverfault.com). If you’re looking for a different topic, it might be covered on another [Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites).
>
> ### Be specific
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful, relevant answer.
>
> ### Make it relevant to others
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.
>
> ### Keep an open mind
>
> The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but that doesn’t mean it is wrong. A conclusive answer isn’t always possible. When in doubt, ask people to cite their sources, or to explain how/where they learned something. Even if we don’t agree with you, or tell you exactly what you wanted to hear, remember: we’re just trying to help.

В этом тексте есть поле для поиска и галочка о том, что человек будет учитывать то, что сказано в этом тексте при задании вопроса. После того, как пользователь нажмёт на кнопку <kbd>proceed</kbd>, ему покажут поле стандартное поле ввода вопроса от незарегистрированного участника.

Думаю, есть смысл реализовать что-то подобное и у нас. Нужно только придумать соответствующее наполнение этой странички.

Comment: Быстрый обход нескольких первых сайтов списка показал, что такая фича, возможно, есть только у serverfault =)

Comment: Эта страница имеется на трёх сайтах: [so], [su], и [electronics.se] ([источник](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4008570#4008570)). Я [предложил](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21512) включить её на [math.se], но пока что этого не произошло.

Comment: Отличная штука и у нас наверняка можно будет ее включить.

Comment: Для начала текст можно просто перевести с небольшими корректировками. Все очень неплохо написано.

Comment: Будь такая возможность, может быть и не стал бы тут регистрироваться.

Comment: @dsnk не очень понял, вы говорите, что эта фича хорошая или плохая?

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev Хорошая, тут начинаешь втягиваться в "секту" любителей плюшек и печенек, вместо работы.

Comment: @Discord проверка обращения к автору правки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Сработало? =)

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev да, всегда срабатывает.

Answer (score 3):

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском!

Для увеличения шансов того, что ваш вопрос не закроют и он получит ответ, убедитесь, что он касается программирования и связанных с этим тем. Если ваш вопрос касается русского языка, задайте его в [соответствующей части сообщества](https://rus.stackexchange.com/). Прочитайте также несколько наших советов:

### Ищите и исследуйте

Вы уже достаточно [тщательно поискали ответ](/search) перед тем, как задать вопрос? Расскажите нам о том, что вы нашли (на этом сайте или где-либо ещё) за это время по теме своего вопроса, и почему это не помогло решить его решить. Это поможет нам точнее представить вашу проблему, а также покажет, что вы потратили некоторое время, пытаясь решить вопрос самостоятельно. Так вы избавите нас от необходимости публиковать тривиальные ответы, а также позволите дать вам более конкретный и релевантный ответ!

Попробуйте также расширенный поиск!

### Задавайте вопросы по теме сообщества

Наше сообщество специализируется на определённом [наборе тем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), связанных с программированием. Пожалуйста, придерживайтесь этих тем, задавая вопрос, [избегайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) спрашивать чьё-то мнение *(мнение не может быть истиной)*, а также не создавайте вопросы-обсуждения. Если ваш вопрос касается непосредственно самого сайта, задайте его на [мета-сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Для вопросов по русскому языку тоже есть своё [сообщество](https://rus.stackexchange.com/). Если вы владете английским языком, вы можете попробовать [найти сайт из сети Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites), подходящий под вашу тематику и задать свой вопрос там.

### Будьте конкретны

Если вы задаёте нечёткий вопрос, вы получите столь же туманный ответ, но если вы предоставите нам детали и контекст, мы сможем дать вам полезный и точный ответ!

### Сделайте ваш вопрос полезным для остальных

Нам нравится помогать людям, и чем больше — тем лучше. Задайте вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что он может помочь не только вам, но и множеству других людей. Так вы заинтересуете больше участников сообщества, соответственно, больше людей смогут попробовать вам помочь!

### Будьте открыты для беседы

Ответ на ваш вопрос иногда может не совпадать с тем, что вы хотели получить, но это не значит, что ответ неправильный. К сожалению, однозначный и полный ответ не всегда возможен. Также если вы сомневаетесь в содержимом ответа, попросите ответившего сослаться на источник или объяснить, как/где он узнал то, что сообщил вам. Даже если мы не согласны с вами или говорим то, что вы и так уже знаете, помните: **мы всего лишь пытаемся помочь**.

Comment: Раз никто не взялся за перевод, оформил сам)

Comment: Ещё вчера прочитал и плюсанул. Мне всё нравится.

Comment: `избегайте спрашивать чьё-то мнение (мнение не может быть истиной), а также не создавайте вопросы-обсуждения` -- тут сразу всплывают известные высказывания: "*что есть истина?*" и "*а судьи кто*". Но  как я понимаю, дело тут не в переводе а политике (позиции, взгляде на сущность) активной части сообщества (или администрации?)

Comment: Это опечатка, или я смысл не понимаю `и почему это не помогло решить его решить.`?

Comment: @dsnk Это не опечатка, это мой кривой черновой перевод =) Я имел в виду, что бывает полезно указать то, что ты нашёл через поиск и сказать, почему найденные решения не подходят.

Answer (score 3):

Постарался сделать короче, опустив вроде бы не так нужные пункты. Надо бы оптимистическую финальную фразу, но пока не могу придумать.

---

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском!

Мы здесь обсуждаем программирование и связанные с ним темы. Если ваш вопрос не об этом, не стоит задавать его здесь. Если вы не вполне уверены, или ваш вопрос на смежную тему, вот [список тем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), обсуждаемых на этом подсайте.

If you want to ask your question in English, it's going to be off-topic here. Consider asking it on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Несколько советов:

## Ищите и исследуйте

Вы поискали ответ перед тем, как задавать вопрос? Если вы выяснили что-то, поделитесь найденным с нами в вопросе, и объясните, почему это не решает вашу проблему. Таким образом мы лучше поймём ваш вопрос, и увидим, что он не дубликат уже решённой проблемы (ведь никому не хочется отвечать на одно и тоже по нескольку раз!). С другой стороны, и вы не будете получать ответы, которые вам не подходят.

Кстати, у нас есть [расширенный поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search).

## Спрашивайте по теме

Наш формат обсуждения — [вопросы по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), а не котики (хотя котики нам тоже нравятся). Старайтесь не отходить от темы. Вопросы карьеры, мировоззрения и холивары в стиле «Linux против Windows» у нас не в почёте. Не устраивайте опросы наподобие «котаны, а что прикольнее, пых или жаба?». Если хотите спросить что-то о самом сайте, для этого у нас есть [Мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Да, и мы не будем писать за вас вашу домашку, извините.

Comment: Мне кажется, что на этом вводную страничку можно и закончить. Вряд ли найдется много новичков, которые прочтут что-то более длинное, но все равно с общими рекомендациями.

Comment: @avp: Хм. Может быть, вы и правы. Наверное, стоит сделать выжимку. Или убрать всё ненужное вниз, для зануд, которые читают до конца и просматривают все ссылки.

Comment: @VladD думаю, полная версия всё равно имеет смысл, именно для тех, что всё же хочет стать частью сообщества. Но да, выдавать её всем -- это уменьшать процент тех, кто прочитал хоть малую часть.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: Может быть, «хвост» текста свернуть? И добавить ссылку «показать остальное», которая будет его разворачивать?

Comment: @VladD Да, наверное, что-то в этом роде: "Показать расширенные рекомендации"